# A Good Delimiter for Barcodes sent from Objective-C to Java to SQL

Tags: java, objective-c, utf-8, barcode-scanner, delimiter

Assuming I can expect a wide range of the available barcodes out in the wild, what is a good (i.e., safe) utf-8 character to delimit strings sent from iOS to a Java server (and on to SQL, but we can assume the server will break it up before SQL)?

I was going with ":" between strings and ";" at the end. ";" at the end seems safe so far, but  you run into problems quickly with ":", for instance in web URLs.

Comment: What are the possible characters in the barcodes? Just digits?

Comment: That's kind of the problem. The set of possible characters is hard to get a grasp on because there are so many barcode standards. QR codes allow almost anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the kinds of barcodes you are going to send. If they are GTIN/EAN/UPC hen anything bu numbers will be fine. For everything else I wouldn't delimit, but upload in a structured fomat like XML or JSON and have the contents be propertly encoded, i.e. base64 in JSON or CDATA in XML.

Comment: My homebrew ended up being so close to JSON that when I finally got around to looking at JSON there was some serious face-palming involved.

Comment: @anthropomo did you reinvent the JSON wheel? :-)

Comment: It was basically `"key:value":"key1:value2":` which was easy enough to manually build and parse back into a map, but likely an eventual disaster and, yes, a JSON wheel reinvention.